# Android copy database to mnt/shared

Tags: android

How can I copy a database from `/data/data/my.package.name/databases/` to the `/mnt/shared` folder using Java?

I tried using `FileOutputStream` but get `open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

Comment: Mostly you are missing to declare the permission to write to externam storage: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: Never saw a /mnt/shared directory. What kind of device is this?

Comment: It's a virtual device using VirtualBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
public void writeToSDCard() throws IOException {


        System.out.println("Write To Sd");
        File f=new File("/data/data/com.yourpackage/databases/dbname");
        FileInputStream fis=null;
        FileOutputStream fos=null;

        try{
            fis=new FileInputStream(f);


            fos=new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/dumped.db");
            while(true){
                int i=fis.read();
                if(i!=-1){
                    fos.write(i);
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
            }
            fos.flush();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        finally{
            try{
                fos.close();
                fis.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ioe){
                //      System.out.println(ioe);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Wrote to Sd");
    }
```

Add the required permission in Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Is there no way for saving it to the `/mnt/shared` folder instead of `/mnt/sdcard`?

Comment: Yes make sure the folder is present. Path is a path no difference it makes. So your final path would be `mnt/sdcard/shared`

Comment: But the there is a different between `/mnt/shared` and `mnt/sdcard/shared`. One is located in the internal storage and the other in the external.

Comment: The path really does not matter unless it is not map-able.

Comment: This exception `open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)` is thrown now.

Comment: That is because your path is not proper to write, are you sure of the path and that of permission to write? I think that path is read only.

Comment: Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getRootDirectory())

Comment: Thanks seems not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution for the problem. Root of the phone is needed.

```
public static void copyDb() {
    try {
        String command = "cp -r /data/data/my.package.name/databases/ /mnt/shared/";
        Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("chmod 777 " + sharedFolder + " \n");
        os.flush();
        os.writeBytes(command + "\n");
        os.flush();
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
        suProcess.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```